# Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(132710400bytes) bitmap. at

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, canvas

> Mi aplicacion se cierra y este es el error que veo en Google Play Console

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(132710400bytes) bitmap.
at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:17423)
at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:17359)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17171)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16946)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3776)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3562)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16157)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16946)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3776)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3562)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16157)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16946)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3776)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3562)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16157)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16946)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3776)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3562)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16157)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16946)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3776)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3562)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17183)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:777)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:682)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:688)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:796)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2947)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2738)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2314)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1310)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6550)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:887)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:689)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6459)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)

Comment: Como tratas de cargar la imagen?, que medida tiene la imagen o imagenes?, agrega mas informacion a tus preguntas, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: No hay ninguna imagen. No estoy cargando imagen.